# Bash IF pass although it shouldnt

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I'm trying to do a simple if, but somehow it doesnt work.

The code:

```
if [ `cat /tmp/rcrt_unusable_indexes.log | grep -i "ORA-" | wc -l` > 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR at in /tmp/rcrt_unusable_indexes.log . EXIT script."  >> ${LOG_PATH}
    exit 1;
fi
```

Test:

```
bash-4.1$ cat /tmp/rcrt_unusable_indexes.log | grep -i "ORA-" | wc -l
0
bash-4.1$ if [ `cat /tmp/rcrt_unusable_indexes.log | grep -i "ORA-" | wc -l` > 0 ]
> then
> echo 1
> fi
1        <------- this is the result
```

How can it be?

Comment: `grep` can read files; use `grep -i "ORA-" /tmp/rcrt_unusable_indexes.log | wc -l`; in fact, it can count, too: `grep -i -c "ORA-" /tmp/rcrt_unusable_indexes.log`.  Also, don't forget to remove the file called `0` from your current directory.  Your invocation of `[` creates that file.  You could use `[[ ... ]]` and use the `>` instead of `[ ... ]` and `-gt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this comparisons, use `-gt`:

```
if [ `cat /tmp/rcrt_unusable_indexes.log | grep -i "ORA-" | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then...
```

It is always better to get rid of the Useless Use of cat, as well as `$()` instead of ``:

```
if [ $(grep -i "ORA-" /tmp/rcrt_unusable_indexes | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
```

More references in [Bash Reference Manual - Bash conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use `wc` and check the result. `grep` will succeed if any matches are found (which corresponds to non-empty output) and fail otherwise. Test the exit status of `grep` directly, instead of testing the exit status of the `[` command.

```
if grep  -q -i "ORA-" /tmp/rcrt_unusable_indexes; then
```

The `-q` prevent `grep` from actually producing any output, which you don't need when you are just checking the exit status.